# "overflow evaluating the requirement" when trying to defer associated types

Tags: rust

In Rust, I'm trying to defer types in order to test decoupled high-level logic. Ideally, I want to express the minimal relationship rules as type constraints on associated types. In this simplified example, the only critical relationship between the error types is that their values can be converted from low-level to high-level.

While these relationships seem like they should terminate, the compiler faults with  "overflow evaluating the requirement." I cannot determine if my type functions are flawed or if I am up against a known or unknown limitation in Rust. Example:

```rust
pub trait CapabilityA {
    type Error;
    fn perform_a(&self) -> Result<String, Self::Error>;
}

pub trait CapabilityB {
    type Error;
    fn perform_b(&self, a: &str) -> Result<(), Self::Error>;
}

pub trait Application {
    type Error;
    fn go(&self) -> Result<(), Self::Error>;
}

impl<T> Application for T
where
    T: CapabilityA + CapabilityB,
    <T as Application>::Error: From<<T as CapabilityA>::Error> + From<<T as CapabilityB>::Error>,
{
    fn go(&self) -> Result<(), Self::Error> {
        let a = self.perform_a()?;
        let b = self.perform_b(&a)?;
        Ok(b)
    }
}
```

Compiler responds:

```
error[E0275]: overflow evaluating the requirement `<Self as Application>::Error`
  --> src/lib.rs:11:1
   |
11 | / pub trait Application {
12 | |     type Error;
13 | |     fn go(&self) -> Result<(), Self::Error>;
14 | | }
   | |_^
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Application` for `Self`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler example [reproducing the same error](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9ddc3a96c3c103c1f475733117ca099c) is:

```rust
pub trait Foo {}

pub trait Application {
    type Error;
}

impl<T> Application for T where <T as Application>::Error: Foo {}
```

Your definition of `Application` is recursive. To know what `T`s implement `Application`, you need to evaluate `<T as Application>`, which requires the compiler to know what `T`s implement `Application`, and so on.

In the implementation of `Application`, you have to choose a concrete `Error`, for example [here with `String`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9e8a5de472fc75c150ddcbd9576f51dd):

```rust
impl<T> Application for T
where
    T: CapabilityA + CapabilityB,
    String: From<<T as CapabilityA>::Error>,
    String: From<<T as CapabilityB>::Error>,
{
    type Error = String;

    fn go(&self) -> Result<(), Self::Error> {
        let a = self.perform_a()?;
        let b = self.perform_b(&a)?;
        Ok(b)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @mcarton. I made a version that worked that way but I was hoping that errors (and some other) definitions could be made in an application assembly or wiring module--leaving the business logic testable in isolation.

Comment: The thing I don't get is why the compiler doesn't know to terminate when it finds that `T as Application` is what is being defined. Is it that it cannot for some reason or just that it's not implemented that way?

Comment: @aztecrex The compiler could catch the error before, but what would be the point? The code still couldn't compile because you've never actually set `Error` anywhere, just set some constraints on it, and there is already logic in the compiler to prevent infinitely recursive bounds, which is the "overflow evaluating the requirement" error you got. There isn't much point in detecting that particular case given these.

Comment: not catch an error. by terminate I mean stop recursing. it seems there is enough information for the compiler to successfully complete the bounds computation without error

Comment: But there isn't enough information! You've never actually specified the type for `Error`. Even if you ignore the bound, you are missing a `type Error = `.

Comment: Yes.but the whole thing is not actually specifying a type, just a constraint. I am trying to express: "given some type T with these constraints, whose associated Error type meets these other constraints that are dependent on T, here is how you implement Application." But in Rust, I do not have the opportunity to defer that concrete Error association. Something like `impl<T,E> ... { type Error = E; ... }` (not valid in Rust). Type families or some other way to express complex type functions would be nice. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @mcarton's answer and its discussion, an alternative that does compile and expresses my intent is:

```rust
pub trait CapabilityA {
    type Error;
    fn perform_a(&self) -> Result<String, Self::Error>;
}

pub trait CapabilityB {
    type Error;
    fn perform_b(&self, a: &str) -> Result<(), Self::Error>;
}


pub trait HasApplicationError: {
    type Error;
}

pub trait Application : HasApplicationError {
    fn go(&self) -> Result<(), Self::Error>;
}

impl<T> Application for T
where
    T: CapabilityA + CapabilityB + HasApplicationError,
    <T as HasApplicationError>::Error: From<<T as CapabilityA>::Error> + From<<T as CapabilityB>::Error>,
{
    fn go(&self) -> Result<(), Self::Error> {
        let a = self.perform_a()?;
        let b = self.perform_b(&a)?;
        Ok(b)
    }
}
```

It is a little more code than I'd hoped but it seems fine.