# Rust complaining that I'm "overflow evaluating the requirement"

Tags: rust

Just getting into rust and it's been a super interesting journey so far, but I've come across my first compiler error that **all** my best google and stack overflow skills haven't been able to fix.

The problem arose in a slightly more complicated bit of code but I've managed to distil it into this little snippet:

```
pub trait FooTrait {}

pub trait BarTrait {
    type Foo
    where
        Self::Foo: FooTrait;
}

struct FooImpl {}

impl FooTrait for FooImpl {}

struct BarImpl {}

impl BarTrait for BarImpl {
    type Foo = FooImpl;
}
```

When I try and compile this I get the error

```
error[E0275]: overflow evaluating the requirement `<BarImpl as BarTrait>::Foo == _`
  --> src/main.rs:13:16
   |
13 |     type Foo = FooImpl;
   |                ^^^^^^^
```

I've been scratching my head about this for a couple of days now so any input would be very welcome; it really doesn't feel like I am asking something to do something unreasonable... I have a trait with an associated type in it that is bounded to have a different trait.

If you think what I'm trying to do is stupid in the first place I can supply a more concrete example of the actual problem at hand; I just figured this was easier to read.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55857823/overflow-evaluating-the-requirement-when-trying-to-defer-associated-types) stack overflow question seems a bit similar, but I cannot figure out how what I am trying to do is recursive in any way

just about every combination of type bounding I could conceive; what I expected it to do was compile without an error.. what it actually did was refuse to compile.

There are a few similar questions about this error on stack overflow but none of them seem to be the same to my inexperienced eyes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this syntax instead:

```
pub trait BarTrait {
    type Foo: FooTrait;
}
```

My naive understanding is that specifying a constraint on `Self::Foo` requires the compiler to look up if `Self` implements `BarTrait`. However this constraint appears *while it is currently evaluating* if `BarImpl` implements `BarTrait` and therefore recurses without bound. The `where` clause is designed for cases where you can't use the above syntax.

This is reported as [issue #87755](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/87755). Whether intentional behavior or not, hopefully we will at least get a better diagnostic message.

Comment: Thank you so much, this at least means I am not going mad :)